# Spring: Sporadically getting No handler found for portlet request

Tags: java, spring

I've been having some issues with NoHandlerException's in a multi server configuration. I've been trying to figure out exactly when I get this exception but
I can not find any good description on what it actually means that no handler was found.

The thing here is that everything actually seems to work fine, we are not receiving any error reports on this from our production system, and we are not able
to reproduce the error in our test systems. But we can clearly see a big amount of no handler found errors in our production logs.

**So my question is**, could this error be due to some bad load-balancing? Like that we send our users between
different servers and the server receiving server does not have an updated state for this user/session? Or should it be some configuration error on the Spring-application
that can not be affected by the load balancing?

When I have searched for other people with the same error they seem to get it all the time, but I get it only sporadically

The error we receive:

```
Uncaught service() exception root cause AppName: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.portlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler found for portlet request: mode 'view', phase 'ACTION_PHASE', parameters map['action' -> array<String>['myController.parameter']]
```

Comment: may you post your portlet and spring configuration code?

Comment: I was hoping that someone could explain the error, like what does spring actually mean when this error occurs. I have seen on http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/NoHandlerFoundException.html that it can be thrown at 404 but we do not have any throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound property set.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check xml somewhere contains portlet. Normally every handler stage error cased by configuration.